# UINavigtion controller back button do not show properly

Tags: ios11, navigationbar, uitabbaritem

Native back buttons are buggy on iOS 11 as shown in the picture. Is there a solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeAutomatic;

Comment: yes but not working .

Comment: you added any code for setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment ? This will be reason for this issue.

Comment: No i am not using it.

Comment: But i am using IQKeyboardManager which used this code.

Comment: Solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193204/custom-back-indicator-image-and-ios-11

Comment: IQKeyboardManager uses setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment  .

Comment: See this :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193204/custom-back-indicator-image-and-ios-11/47296635#47296635

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code to solve that. Leace the comment below if it not work for you.

```
    var backImage = UIImage(named: "back_button_image").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    let leftPadding: CGFloat = 10
    let adjustSizeForBetterHorizontalAlignment: CGSize = CGSize(width: backImage.size.width + leftPadding, height: backImage.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(adjustSizeForBetterHorizontalAlignment, false, 0)
    backImage.draw(at: CGPoint(x: leftPadding, y: 0))
    backImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Comment: i am not using custom image.its default back button of navigation bar.

Comment: i also used your code but same problem

Comment: Can you give mor information about that?. Even when I tried to remove all of that just keep back button with blank title, I still not reproduce that yet.

Comment: when i push to second controller then back button of second controller allignment issue. same issue is in whole application of all controllers. Only on ios 11 . But working fine on bellow ios 11.

Comment: Honestly, I can not reproduce that, Can you share your source for a quick help.

Comment: Finally i resolve issue . Select navigation bar  in storyboard and then select  "show the attribute inspector " and then add back button image. Otherwise no any solution found.

Comment: @MianShahbazAkram is there any solution without adding image on back button ?

Comment: yet not found perhaps apple will fix it in next version. I also reported to Apple.