# iOS11 backBarButtonItem disabled

Tags: ios, ios11

Before `iOS11`, I use the runtime replaced the `backBarButtonItem` implementation change the default back button style, effects as follows, but on the `iOS11`  is invalid.

[image: effect]

I found that the structure of the back button below before `iOS11`

[image: effect]

But The structure of the back button on the `iOS11` below

[image]

How can I get on iOS11 before implementation effect, which means `backBarButtonItem` without words?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193204/custom-back-indicator-image-and-ios-11

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
```

wrire this code in viewDidLoad().

Its affected in NextViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only backButton without the words, try going through following steps:

1. Embed your second ViewController to NavigationController too.
2. Drag and Drop a UIBarButton icon to the NavigationBar of Second ViewController.
3. Add the backbutton image to the UIBarButton.

It's Done!!

Hope it will help you.