# How to fix iPhoneX back button image position?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, iphone-x

I am getting issue with iPhoneX back button image. It is not in right position as you can see in the screenshot

[image]

I am using below code for setting back image

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn-back")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "btn-back")
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -80.0), for: .default)
        return true
    }
}
```

Can anyone please explain why it's not at correct position and how to fix this ?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193204/custom-back-indicator-image-and-ios-11

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `topItem?.title` for setting up Navigation title as:

**Method 1:**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Method 2:**

```
 let yourBackImage = UIImage(named: "back-Image")
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .red//.blue as you required
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = yourBackImage
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = yourBackImage
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""
```

**Output:**

[image]

Note: As [Apple Human Interface GuideLine](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/) The navigation bar back image size should be-

> 75px × 75px(3x)

[image]

Sample image 3x(75 x 75)-

[image]